# If I remove permissions will my Android app updates go back to automatic?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I made some changes to my Android app that required some new permissions, and have since noticed that a significant number of users haven't adopted the latest version due to the need for them to manually install the update.

The change that required the new permissions would be nice to have but it isn't critical, so I'm considering removing it and setting the permissions back to what they were in the previous version and re-releasing in the hopes that everyone will go back to auto updates.

Is that how it works? If I do that will those users who haven't updated go back to automatic updates and get the latest version, or will they be required to manually update the app until they are at or beyond the version with the permission change?

Comment: Your permissions have nothing to do with what your users do. Any change you make has no effect on your user. If the user is using manual updates nothing you can do will make them switch to automatic.

Comment: I'm not asking about users who have auto updates turned off. I know I can't control what they do. I added new permissions to my app, and when you add permissions it requires all users to manually update and approve the new permissions. I'm asking if removing those permissions and posting a new version will go back to auto updating those users.

Comment: @Dijonase Why are you using outdated Android / caring about the old Android devices? Is you app just for pre Android M ?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot This issue affects all users, regardless of Android version. I added a feature to my app and had to add a new permission to the manifest. This required that all users would have to manually update the app, because the new permission is in Android's "dangerous" list (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE). I want to know if releasing a new app version after removing that feature and the corresponding permission will set everyone who has updates set to automatic back to automatic, or if they'll still have to manually update the new app version.

Comment: Don't know that and I don't even know if anyone knows. I guess it could be possible that it is not documented. But since Android M (23) you don't need to accept the permissions on download so I think that it should work for all new versions of android.